# `to_s` isn't converting an integer to a string

Tags: ruby, puts

I am calling `to_s` within a method:

```
$  def my_function(num)
$    number = num.to_s.split(//)
$    puts number
$  end

$  my_function(233)
2
3
3
# => nil
```

It looks to me like within the function, no array is created since the output is `nil`. Why is an array of strings not created when `to_s.split(//)` is called inside a method?

Also, why is the output for `puts number` seemingly just each digit on its own line? Do I need to explicitly create the array within the function and then explicitly push the split number into it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call `puts` on an array, it outputs each element of the array separately with a newline after each element. To confirm that your `to_s` methods are converting the number to a string, try using `print` instead of `puts`.

As for the `nil` that's output, that is the return value of your function.  Unless there is an explicit `return`, the return value of a function will be the evaluation of the last line, which in your case is: `puts number`.  The return value of `puts number` is `nil`; printing the value of `number` is a side effect, not the return value.

I'm curious as to why the output was indeed an array in your first lines of code (not within the function):

```
$  num = 233
$  number = num.to_s.split(//)
$  puts number
=> ['2', '3', '3']
```

I suspect that you actually saw that output after the `num.to_s.split(//)` line, not the `puts number` line.

Answer (score 5):

Your function is calling `puts number`.  That will display it, not return it.  `puts` returns nil which is why your call to `my_function(233)` is returning nil. The reason that the output is a single number on each line is because that is what `puts` does when an array is passed to it.  One element per line.

Try this code:

```
puts [1,2,3]

puts '=' * 40

def my_function(num)
  num.to_s.split(//)
end

x =  my_function(233)

p x
```

When run the output is:

```
1
2
3
========================================
["2", "3", "3"]
```

The key difference is that `my_function` no longer displays any output.  It just returns the result.  It's important to remember that a ruby method will return the last evaluated statement as it's result.  That is to say the above method is the same as this:

```
def my_function(num)
  return num.to_s.split(//)
end
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. I was relying on implicit returns, not realizing I was overriding them with puts. That solved it.

Answer (score 3):

The array you see in your first snippet is the result of the evaluation of the split function. Try this outside of the function : `puts [1,2,3]` , and you'll see that the results didn't vary.

Use `print` if you want it to print it the cute way.

Best regards